# Visual Studio 2013 changes SharePoint project guid

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

We using VS 2013 to develop SharePoint solutions.
Our outsource team is using VS2012 to develop SharePoint solutions.
Unfortunately, the outsource team is not able to upgrade the version as of now.

VS2013 upgrades the SharePoint projects and changes the GUID in the .csproj file.

The problem we are having is that when we check the .csproj file in TFS, the outsourced team is not able to get the latest as it is and they are required to change back the GUID in the .csproj file manually.

It is very hard and very counter productive.

Has anyone of you been through such situation?
Any tips/suggestions would be much helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

No easy OOB solution for what I know.
The easiest thing I can think of is a gated check in build that parse the project files and fails if detect the VS 2013 change.